# Where is the API or CLI that shows a user or group permission

Tags: azure, api, permissions, command-line-interface, devops

I am trying to write a script showing all permissions related to a specific user or group (for the collection, every project, and object).

I've searched everywhere for an API or the CLI command that provides the permission for a user or group for a specific namespace.  When I use the az devops security permission show command, I get back "Not Set" for every single permission.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do this [Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) Rest API in Azure devops graph helpful?

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I can't seem to find any API that shows effective permissions.